# remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio

Exception is emitted from `io_service:run` on Linux.

This is what happens. I implemented simple asynchronous echo server using Boost.Asio. It is single threaded and everything is asynchronous, that is I use only asynchronous versions of accept, send and receive functions. When a client doesn't disconnect gracefully (e.g. it crashes) server's event loop throws boost::system::system_error exception **remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected**. Why it happens an how to deal with it? Is it caused by SIGPIPE signal? If so, what is the best way to keep the server running? Handle exception or handle signal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception indicates that the throwing version of [`basic_stream_socket::remote_endpoint()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/remote_endpoint.html) was invoked, where in the underlying call to [`getpeername()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeername) returned with an error of `ENOTCONN`.  Per the [effect of exceptions thrown from handlers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers) documentation, exceptions thrown within a handler are permitted to propagate up through the throwing thread's invocation of `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()`.

To resolve this, consider either:

- Invoking the non-throwing version of [`basic_stream_socket::remote_endpoint()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/remote_endpoint/overload2.html), and handle the error appropriately:

  ```
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket.remote_endpoint(ec);
  if (ec)
  {
    // An error occurred.  Stop the asynchronous call chain for
    // this connection.
  }
  ```
- Invoke `run()` from within a `try`/`catch` block.  The following code is mentioned in the documentation:

  ```
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  ...
  for (;;)
  {
    try
    {
      io_service.run();
      break; // run() exited normally
    }
    catch (my_exception& e)
    {
      // Deal with exception as appropriate.
    }
  }
  ```

  With this approach, the thread may re-invoke [`run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) without the need of invoking [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) on the `io_service`.

Comment: Invoking the non-throwing version of the function is not a way to solve the problem. To solve the problem is to find out why the exception "remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected" happens in the first place.